# mysql encoding utf-8 not working

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8

I changed charset of database, tables and columns into UTF-8 :

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE collection CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
ALTER TABLE collection MODIFY title VARCHAR(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

And I inserted data into this table.

```
insert into collection (title) values ('Enfants et bébés');
```

Actually, data is inserted from a .sql file which is encoded in UTF-8 :

```
source collections.sql
```

The trouble is that the encoding fails :

```
select * from collection
+----+------------------------+
| id | title                  |
+----+------------------------+
| 17 | Enfants et BÃ©bÃ©s     |
+----+------------------------+
```

I don't understand what's wrong.
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
The trouble cames from mysql client which is not in UTF-8 :

```
SET NAMES utf8
```